# Develop Angular SPA on localhost and query the remote staging API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, csrf, x-xsrf-token

I have troubles setting up my development environment.

I am attempting to develop an Angular SPA which should, in the end, communicate with a Laravel backend that is hosted under the same top domain name.

For ease of developement, I am hosting my API on a remote location, let's say :

my-api.myhost.com

Now, when I am working on my Angular SPA, I am working on localhost. Meaning, I have to do queries on my-api.myhost.com

Obviously, this wouldn't work since I must do POST request which are blocked if the X-XSRF-TOKEN is not present in the Headers of the request.

The problems comes from the fact that I am retrieving the cookies but unable to set them in the header of my request since the domain do not match (.myhost.com vs localhost)

How can I conveniently develop my app on localhost and hit the remote backend server ?

Comment: This sounds like a good time to familiarise yourself with docker containers instead of trying to allow remote cookies on your server.

Comment: I am familiar with docker, I do not want to use docker. This wasn't my question.

Comment: *For ease of developement* - apparently it's not as easy as you thought.

Comment: It is not, I'd love to use docker and go on with my development, sadly, I am not the only one working on the project - trust me, it's easier to go through this painful process than convince my teammates to change their mind.

Comment: Have you discussed this problem with your teammates?  Potentially your not the only one with this issue.

Comment: Yes, that's how I ended up on StackOverflow. That and me trying to make those proxies work.

Comment: I'd have thought standard procedure for a dev environment would be to host the backend locally too, and talk to that. I'd also question why the setup involves cookie-based stuff when it's a split front-end / back-end thing. What are the cookies for? If it's for Session / authentication then I'd argue there's potentially a design flaw there - token-based auth might be a more appropriate scheme. And you may also run into other CORS-related issues if the Angular app is making ajax requests to the backend, these probably need addressing too.

Comment: Thanks for the useful input @ADyson I'll look into that :) !

Comment: Wouldn't running it on `angular.myhost.com` and setting that in the hosts file to localhost work in lying to the backend that you're on the same domain?

Comment: I suppose it could work, yes. I should give it a try.